# How do you programmatically apply a css class?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have in an aspx page, some constructions like this:

```
<div class="weather time-morning active">
<div class="icon">
<i class="sun"></i>
</div>
<div class="content">
<h3>Morning</h3>
<div class="degrees">- 1</div>
<div class="data">
<h2>Sunny</h2>

<div>Wind: E 7 mph</div>
<div>Humidity: 91%</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want in code behind to apply various classes to the  tag (and/or add more than one  tags, in conjunction to various conditions:

```
switch (response.currently.summary.ToString())
{
case ("Partly Cloudy"):
//do something
//< i class="cloud windy"></i>
break;
case ("Sunny"):
//do something
//<i class="sun"></i>
//<i class="cloud"></i>
//<i class="sprinkles"></i>
break;
}
```

I have to say that I started from a static HTML page that mimic the behaviour I want.

Any hints please?

L.E.

For being more precise the whole HTML construction is (statically) like this:

```
<section>
  <div class="weather time-morning active">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="sun"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Morning</h3>
      <div class="degrees">- 1</div>
      <div class="data">          
        <h2>Sunny</h2>
        <div>Wind: E 7 mph</div>
        <div>Humidity: 91%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="weather time-day">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="sun"></i>
      <i class="cloud windy"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Day</h3>
      <div class="degrees">+ 3</div>
      <div class="data">          
        <h2>Mostly Sunny</h2>
        <div>Wind: N 5 mph</div>
        <div>Humidity: 45%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="weather time-evening">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="sun"></i>
      <i class="cloud"></i>
      <i class="sprinkles"></i>
      <i class="sprinkles"></i>
      <i class="sprinkles"></i>
      <i class="sprinkles"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Evening</h3>
      <div class="degrees">0</div>
      <div class="data">          
        <h2>Rainy</h2>
        <div>Wind: W 12 mph</div>
        <div>Humidity: 91%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="weather time-night">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="moon"></i>
      <i class="cloud"></i>
      <div class="snowflakes">
        <i class="snowflake"></i>
        <i class="snowflake"></i>
        <i class="snowflake"></i>
        <i class="snowflake"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Night</h3>
      <div class="degrees">- 2</div>
      <div class="data">          
        <h2>Cloudy</h2>
        <div>Wind: N 2 mph</div>
        <div>Humidity: 47%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and here conditionally I have to change the  tags accordingly to the switch values.

Comment: for both responses to this moment: in fact, more relevant I think to do this to the <I> tag? but here is an issue that is not clear to me: based on various conditions, I think to have one, or more <I> tags. But I don't know at design time how many tags goes on. More clear: the first <I> tag (sun) means day. If is cloudy, comes another one, and if also rains comes a third <I> tag. If is night, at very bottom "sun" becomes "moon" and if necessary comes the second, the third etc.

Comment: Dynamically adding new html elements to a div from code heind seems a different question to the original one (not related how to add css classes from code behind)?

Comment: In fact the issue consist in both: first adding conditionally the <I> tag and then assigning adequate CSS class. The code that I illustrate is the static one (what I suppose to obtain).

Answer (score 2):

Initially, you have to make your div elements enabled for server side control. In terms of code:

```
<div id="DivId" runat="server"></div>
```

Then you could make your checks in your server side code and add the class you want like below:

```
DivId.CssClass="the name of the css class";
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'nice' way of doing this would be to change the control you are trying to modify to runat="server" in your `aspx`

```
<div id="weatherDiv" runat="server">
```

And then in your code behind, you can now access the div:

```
weatherDiv.CssClass = "weather time-morning active";
```

You can also hack a more `MVC Razor` paradigm to this with Bind `<%#`, without the need for a control:

.cs Code Behind

```
protected string GetWeatherClass(bool extraSprinkles)
{
   return extraSprinkles
     ? "extraSprinkesClass"
     : "";
}
```

.ASPX

```
<div class="weather <%# GetWeatherClass(true) %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

based on suggestions, finally I have this approach (don't know if the best, but at least it woks)(MorningTime, MorningDay etc. are ID for corespinding tags):

```
       switch (response.currently.icon.ToString())
        {
            case ("clear-day"):
                //do something
                MorningTime.Attributes.Add("class", "sun");
                MorningType.Attributes.Add("class", "sun");
                DayTime.Attributes.Add("class", "sun");
                DayType.Attributes.Add("class", "sun");
                break;
            case ("partly-cloudy-day"):
                //do something
                MorningTime.Attributes.Add("class", "sun");
                MorningType.Attributes.Add("class", "cloud windy");
                DayTime.Attributes.Add("class", "sun");
                DayType.Attributes.Add("class", "cloud windy");
                EveningTime.Attributes.Add("class", "sun");
                EveningType.Attributes.Add("class", "cloud windy");
                NightTime.Attributes.Add("class", "moon");
                NightType.Attributes.Add("class", "cloud windy");
                break;
            case ("rain"):
```

and so on.